# Making one project's jars available to another dependent project

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have two projects X and Y. ProjectX needs jars so I added them to its classpath. ProjectY needs the classes in ProjectX but also needs the classes in the jars that were added to ProjectX. When I add ProjectX to ProjectY's class path, I get an error that Eclipse doesn't find the classes of the jars in its classpath. How to solve this? I mean is the only choice is to also add the jars to ProjectY's class path?

Comment: Yes, you also need the other jars in the classpath.

Comment: A tool like Maven or Gradle will handle all of this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have cross references.

Class A in jar X needs class B in jar Y. But class B also need class A...

*Solution:* Create a superclass for A in jar Y.

**In jar X:**

- Class A (extends GenericA)

**In jar Y:**

- Class GenericA
- Class B

Another solutionis to define an interface in jar Y that class A could implement in jar X.